# C++ full-expression standard wording

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, standards

In [paragraph 12](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.execution#12) of [intro.execution] in the current (C++ 17) C++ standard draft there is written:

> A *full-expression is:*
>
> [...]
>
> - an expression that is not a subexpression of another expression and that is not otherwise part of a full-expression.
>
> If a language construct is defined to produce an implicit call of a function, **a use** of the language construct is considered to be an expression for the purposes of this definition. [...]

The "use of the language construct" wording refers to the fact that the construct itself is to be considered an expression or the implicit calls that the construct "uses" are to be considered as expressions?

I am asking this because in the same paragraph there is this code sample:

```
S s1(1);                   // full-expression is call of S​::​S(int)
```

The comment would indicate that the second interpretation is correct.

However, the paragraph explicitly says that an *init-declarator* is a *full-expression*, which would indicate that the comment is wrong.

In the past (I believe even before C++03), this paragraph looked like this (taken from [this defect report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#392)):

> A full-expression is an expression that is not a subexpression of another expression. If a language construct is defined to produce an implicit call of a function, a use of the language construct is considered to be an expression for the purposes of this definition.
>
> [Note: certain contexts in C++ cause the evaluation of a full-expression that results from a syntactic construct other than expression (5.19 [expr.comma]). For example, in 8.6 [dcl.init] one syntax for initializer is
>
> ( expression-list )
>
> but the resulting construct is a function call upon a constructor function with expression-list as an argument list; **such a function call is a full-expression**. For example, in 8.6 [dcl.init], another syntax for initializer is
>
> = initializer-clause
>
> but again the resulting construct might be a function call upon a constructor function with one assignment-expression as an argument; again, **the function call is a full-expression**. ]

This is another reason for believing that the second interpretation is the one intended.

I know that it makes no difference to the understanding of the language, but I just want to know what was the intention of the person who initially wrote that paragraph.

Comment: Yes, I think the comment is wrong. The init declarator is a full expression and considered to be an expression and the constructor call is an immediate subexpression because it's a "any function call that e implicitly invokes". The change to make the init declarator a full-expression was a result of http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1343

Comment: Thank you for your response. But in the initial form of the paragraph, before explicitly making an *init-declarator* a *full-expression*, I assume the comment was correct. Therefore, is the second interpretation correct, that is the passage "**a use** of the language construct is considered to be an expression" means that the implicit call is considered as an expression and not the construct itself?

Comment: the init declarator is considered to be an expression, and the implicit call is considered to be an "immediate subexpression". It's irrelevant what it was called in older Standards as long as the intention was the same. That's why there are defect reports and defects were resolved.

Comment: The only thing that one could IMO complain about is that ", a use of the language construct is considered to be an expression for the purposes of this definition." should perhaps be ", a use of the language construct is considered to be an expression for the purposes of this and the previous definition. " (previous definition = immediate subexpressions).

Comment: So even from the beginning that comment was wrong? Because the notes from the old version all state that the full-expression is the call to the constructor and not the initializer itself.

Comment: In the defect report that I linked to there is this comment: "It is a small point but it is probably worth correcting 1.9 [intro.execution] paragraph 12. Instead of the "implicit call of a function" wording, it might be better to just say that a **full-expression includes any implicit use of the expression value** in the enclosing language construct, and include a note giving implicit calls and lvalue-to-rvalue conversions as examples." This made me think that, again, the construct itself shouldn't be considered an expression.

Comment: Also, if the construct itself is an expression, I imagine that the following construct: "if ( g() ) f();" (where g() returns an lvalue reference of type T, which means that the T to bool conversion function will be implicitly called) would automatically include the lvalue-to-rvalue and T to bool conversions, therefore the defect report would not be necessary.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I kept looking at the history of the definition of full-expressions and I found issue number 694 from http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/1997/N1079.pdf, which contains: "I looked at the wording and I agree it could be clearer. At the least we should make normative the idea that when a construct is implemented by an implicit function call, the **entire function call is considered a full expression** [...]". Unfortunately files documenting issues later than 1997 require authentication. Is there a way to find the resolution of this issue?